# Как вторым циклом добавить в вывод на консоль первого нужные дефолтные значения?

Tags: java, циклы

Есть цикл:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 44; i += 2, k++) {
            System.out.printf("%04d " , i);
            if (k % 5==0)
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
0001 0003 0005 0007 0009 
0011 0013 0015 0017 0019 
0021 0023 0025 0027 0029 
0031 0033 0035 0037 0039 
0041 0043
```

Нужно:

```
0001 0003 0005 0007 0009 
0011 0013 0015 0017 0019 
0021 0023 0025 0027 0029 
0031 0033 0035 0037 0039 
0041 0043 0000 0000 0000
```

Или:

```
0001 0003 0005 0007 0009 
0011 0013 0015 0017 0019 
0021 0023 0025 0027 0029 
0031 0033 0035 0037 0039 
0041 0043    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть счётчик выведенных чисел `k`, *увеличенный на 1*, соответственно нужно вывести столько нулей, сколько не хватает до 5:

```java
int k = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 48; i += 2, k++) {
    System.out.printf("%04d " , i);
    if (k % 5==0)
        System.out.println();
}
k--; // реальное количество выведенных чисел
if (k % 5 != 0) {
    for (int i = k % 5; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%04d ", 0);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Аналогичный вариант с циклом `while`:

```java
int k = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 40; i += 2, k++) {
    System.out.printf("%04d " , i);
    if (k % 5==0)
        System.out.println();
}
boolean printNl = k % 5 != 1;
while ((k - 1) % 5 != 0) {
    System.out.printf("%04d " , 0);
    k++;
}
if (printNl)
    System.out.println();
```

Результаты:

- `i < 40`

```
0001 0003 0005 0007 0009 
0011 0013 0015 0017 0019 
0021 0023 0025 0027 0029 
0031 0033 0035 0037 0039
```

- `i < 44`

```
0001 0003 0005 0007 0009 
0011 0013 0015 0017 0019 
0021 0023 0025 0027 0029 
0031 0033 0035 0037 0039 
0041 0043 0000 0000 0000
```

и т.д.